# My website does not display images on iOS

Tags: html, ios

I have built a custom website, and am viewing it on my iPhone 4 that is running iOS 7. The site has a few images on it, but none of them are loading. All that shows is the image's `alt` tag. The site works fine on my iPhone 6s running iOS 9, and on every other device that I have tested on.

Does anyone know why are the images not loading on my iPhone 4 (running iOS 7)?

Here is a link to the website: http://testingsite1.herokuapp.com

Comment: You could use weinre to see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @DaveWood I've updated the post with a link to the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your images are massive in size!

An image you're displaying at about 250px x 300px is actually 2687px x 3356px. That's way too large. The background image is also too large at 3000px x 2000px.

Make your images smaller if you want them to display on old devices with limited RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Wood. I completely forgot to resize them after downloading them. Do you have any recommended sizes?

Comment: Ideally you have the images as small as needed. And possibly use a script or other method for HiDPI versions.

Answer (score 0):

- Test how well does your browser support html5 on https://html5test.com
- Keep your browser still up to date.
- Test on iPhone 4 with most popular browser like Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and less.
- Use Front-end Framework: Bootstrap, MDL, Semantic UI and more. Style in image will automatically works fine.
- When you develop your website, you can use DevTools to view with device mode on your browser.